# Draw Over Other Apps ~ Disabled / Grayed Out ~

Tags: android

Android states i must ask for permission if my app wants to "Draw over other apps" when on Android v 6.0+. This permission can only be given manually by the user navigating to the appropriate Settings area.

When sent to Settings (via my app calling the intent) i noticed the "Draw over other apps" option for my app is always set to Disabled; it cannot be modified. Furthermore, if one were to navigate to the Apps permissions manually you'll notice the desired app isnt even listed in the "Draw over other apps" page making it impossible to adjust the setting.

I've already followed the baffling instructions by others to disable all the other apps listed then to try running my app again but to no luck. I've also tried restarting the emulator, factory reset, and other emulators. No luck.

Are there any other solutions to resolving this disabled issue?

Comment: Instead of adding "solved" to the title, just accept an answer instead.

Comment: umm, stackexchange blocks such a thing so i can't just "accept an answer" within the min'm time limit.

Comment: Then wait for the required time and then accept the answer - still no need to change the title of the post.

Answer (score 20):

Ok i discovered the problem and this is likely the same issue all others have had. Within my AndroidManifest.xml i forgot to include the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

So add the following just before the application element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Problem solved. Everyone should ignore the ridiculous claim that you need to disable all the other Draw over apps or Force stop others. Completely unnecessary in my case.

Comment: Yes! I too missed the space after WINDOW Like this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW " />`

Just remove the space it will work fine.